# Python : Help for parsing website and extracting data into csv file

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

This is my first question here, feel free to tell me if there is something I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to extract "Title" and "Show time" from a movie website for some sociological study.

My python code is working however it takes only the first index of my list named "horaire" when I would like to include them all in my csv file.

My issue is that I dont know in advance how many index will this list contain.

Find my script below :

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import sys

url = "http://www.allocine.fr/seance/salle_gen_csalle=C0116.html"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

with open('test2306.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    cinemaWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for films in soup.find_all('div',
                               {'class': 'card entity-card entity-card-list movie-card-theater cf hred'}):
        horaire = films.find_all('span',
                               {'class': 'showtimes-hour-item-value'})
        titres = films.find_all('a',
                               {'class': 'meta-title-link'})
        cinemaWriter.writerow([horaire[0:].text.strip(),
                                titres[0:].text.strip()])
```

Thank you for your help <3 !

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] to get all entries of horaire:

You can try this:

```
with open('test2306.csv', 'w') as csvfile:  ## 'w' instead of 'wb'
    cinemaWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for films in soup.find_all('div',
                               {'class': 'card entity-card entity-card-list movie-card-theater cf hred'}):
        horaire = films.find_all('span',
                               {'class': 'showtimes-hour-item-value'})
        titres = films.find_all('a',
                               {'class': 'meta-title-link'})
        
        horaire = ','.join([i.text for i in horaire])

        cinemaWriter.writerow([horaire, titres[0].text])
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your help !  But this does not solve my issue. There are several value in my list horaire and I would like to write them all in my csv file. This only write the first value of the list.

Comment: Happy to help, sorry that I didnt recognize this at the first time. Have a look at my updated code. Now it writes all the entries of horaire to the csv-file.

Comment: Thank you for updating, I'll try this tomorrow !